# Using CASE in Yii CDbCriteria statement

Tags: php, mysql, yii

Can anyone suggest why this CASE statement doesn't work within my Yii CDbCriteria statement?

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->select = array('t.*',
        '(CASE
            WHEN t.type = 3 THEN "Quick Point"
            WHEN t.type = 2 THEN positive.reason
            WHEN t.type = 1 THEN deduction.reason
            END AS reason)');
```

I get the following error:-

```
Active record "OrganisationClassroomRedeemedCodes" is trying to select an invalid column "(CASE 
WHEN t.type = 3 THEN "Quick Point"
WHEN t.type = 2 THEN positive.reason 
WHEN t.type = 1 THEN deduction.reason 
END AS reason)". Note, the column must exist in the table or be an expression with alias.
```

I am essentially trying to do this query using the CDbCriteria builder

```
SELECT `t`.*,
CASE
 WHEN t.type = '3' THEN 'Quick Point' 
 WHEN t.type = '2' THEN positive.reason
 WHEN t.type = '1' THEN deduction.reason
  END AS reason
FROM
`organisation_classroom_redeemed_codes` `t`
 LEFT OUTER JOIN `organisation_classroom_achievements` `positive` ON (
`positive`.`achievement_id` = `t`.`order_product_id`
) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `organisation_classroom_deductions` `deduction` ON (
`deduction`.`deduction_id` = `t`.`order_product_id` 
) 
WHERE (t.myuser_id = 12345)
ORDER BY `t`.`date_redeemed` DESC
```

Comment: I guess you have to remove `()` from case statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it helps anyone else... this is the correct way

```
    $criteria->select = array('t.*',
        '(CASE
            WHEN t.type = 1 THEN deduction.reason
            WHEN t.type = 2 THEN positive.reason
            WHEN t.type = 3 THEN "custom"
            END) AS reason',           
    );
```

Comment: The solution was in the error code: "Note, the column must exist in the table or be **an expression with alias**"